# Is there a way to forward AWS cloudfront request id to the origin?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-waf

I was looking for a unique correlation id to identify request that flows from the cloudfront to the origin and also should be able to relate it with the WAF logs. I see there is a filed named httpRequest.requestId but, this is not visible in the request headers that are being sent to the origin.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "file named `httpRequest.requestId`" - where do you see a file like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `X-Amz-Cf-Id` as this holds the Cloudfront request id, which if you want you can use as a correlation id for the request lifecycle within your backend systems.

> CloudFront adds the header to the viewer request before forwarding the
> request to your origin. The header value contains an encrypted string
> that uniquely identifies the request.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html#request-custom-headers-behavior